# Flutter Amplify - Cannot run appsync code gen for existing api

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have an existing AppSync API that I need to use in a new flutter app.  After initializing amplify in my project, i run the command "amplify add codegen --apiId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

This results in a message saying "Successfully added API xxxx to your amplify project" but then says "Flutter Only supports the command $amplify codegen models."

When I run amplify codegen models, it says No Appsync API configured.  Please add an API.  When I run amplify status, it shows the API ,but with no provider plugin.  If I update the backend-config.json in amplify/backend directory with the awscloudformation provider plugin, and run either amplify push or amplify codegen models it tells me there is no API folder in amplify/backend

Has anyone had success getting codegen to work for an existing appsync api with Flutter?  I have tried everything.

Comment: The only way to currently do this is to run amplify pull and it will re-run the codegen.  If you are not getting the new models, delete the amplify folder and run pull again.  Not ideal but it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the only way seems to be to use the multi-frontend approach found here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend/

Basically, you pull the backend from another project and use the models in Flutter.